# imageNamed returns nil on iOS 7 but not iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

I have images for various time intervals. An example would be "1.5d-4h.png", aka between 4 hours and 1.5 days. I have regular @2x and @3x assets for each interval image and I've made sure that they're all PNGs (not JPGs) but for some reason some interval images fail to load via `imageNamed` only on iOS 7. iOS 8 devices correctly load all possible interval images.

From some further testing it looks like on iOS 7 if you fully qualify the name to `imageNamed` it succeeds with all of these images e.g.

```
(lldb) po [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.5d-4h.png"]
<UIImage: 0x7ec390>

(lldb) po [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.5d-4h"]
 nil
```

An example of an image that loads succesfully on both iOS 7 and 8:

```
(lldb) po [UIImage imageNamed:@"10-9d"]
<UIImage: 0x10cc290>
```

Here's the full set of time intervals:

```
@"4h-0min"
@"1.5d-4h"   // fails
@"4.5-1.5d"  // fails
@"5.5-4.5d"  // fails
@"7-5.5d"    // fails
@"9-7d"
@"10-9d"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: "From some further testing it looks like on iOS 7 if you fully qualify the name to imageNamed it succeeds" So fully qualify the name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like all the image names with a '.' in them fail to load.

Try escaping the '.' characters or rename the images to not have a '.' character in their names.

Comment: `imageNamed` likely uses the dot to try and parse the file extension.

Comment: @thelaws that seems to be what's happening. They must have improved their parsing on iOS 8 to be able to work around '.' characters. I just renamed my time interval images to no longer use '.' characters e.g. "1d12h-4h.png" and it appears to working :)

Answer (score 0):

give a simple image name means without dot (.) as well as check camel case in image name because simulator not care about camelCase but device care.